# Hashed password doesn't match original in Python

Tags: python, hash, passlib

I've two rest endpoints, one that registers an user and the second that lets that user login. This is the code that I'm using to hash the user's password and store the hashed password in the database,

```
from passlib.hash import pbkdf2_sha256
def _get_hashed_password(self, password):
    return pbkdf2_sha256.encrypt(password, rounds=200000, salt_size=16)
```

Now on the login endpoint I use this code to verify the hashed password,

```
password = data['password']
hash = pbkdf2_sha256.encrypt(password, rounds=200000, salt_size=16)
pbkdf2_sha256.verify(user.hashed_password, hash)
```

This method fails and clearly because the two passwords are different,

```
$pbkdf2-sha256$200000$ai0FoDTG2BuDkDKGEIJQKg$Ik06dr61.2rRMDwZCZMdVq.zMe5887.ksDxvmSXFRwE
$pbkdf2-sha256$200000$pHTuHYNwLoXQeu8dI0QoxQ$2z4cZl9Njz9X/bxNtWCZzzeplWO.jTZA2v5lvcmgFE8
```

I'm wondering how can I get this to work?

Comment: [Have you tried doing it like in the first example in the documentation?](https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Comment: @Terminus you mean instead of the encrypt method use the hash method. Otherwise I think everything is exactly the same.

Comment: In addition to what @Terminus said, hashing the same password twice will not give you the same results. Your "hash" actually contains multiple values delimited by dollar signs: `pbkdf2-sha256`, `200000`, `pHTuHYNwLoXQeu8dI0QoxQ`, and `2z4cZl9Njz9X/bxNtWCZzzeplWO.jTZA2v5lvcmgFE8`. The third value is a salt, which is randomly generated and affects the fourth value.

Comment: Previous comment had the wrong answer and so was deleted. And that is why I don't like to answer in the comments.

Comment: @Blender that's what I figured too, so how do I make it work, do I need to store the salt separately or how do I get this to work in two separate rest end points?

Comment: I don't understand why is this question being downvoted?

Comment: Where does `user.hashed_password` come from? Your database?

Comment: @Terminus yes that's the hashed_password stored in the database when the user registered.

Comment: In that case, Blender's answer should be the answer you need. Please do read all of it. Happy Programming!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`pbkdf2_sha256.encrypt` and `pbkdf2_sha256.verify` do more than just compute the hash of your password. Look closely at the output of `pbkdf2_sha256.encrypt`

```
$pbkdf2-sha256$200000$ai0FoDTG2BuDkDKGEIJQKg$Ik06dr61.2rRMDwZCZMdVq.zMe5887.ksDxvmSXFRwE
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$  algorithm  $rounds$         salt         $             the actual hash
```

You can switch algorithms, increase the number of rounds in a few years, and `pbkdf2_sha256.verify` will still be able to verify a plaintext password against the hash stored in your database.

Hashing the same password twice will not give you the same result each time because a random salt is used. The salt prevents [rainbow table attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) in the event an attacker gains access to your password hashes. Basically, instead of computing just `hash(password)`, you compute something like `hash(salt + password)`. Since the salt is already given in the above string and you presumably know the password, you will also know the value of `salt + password` and your life won't be any more difficult. But for an attacker that spent a lot of time pre-computing just `hash(password)`, none of those hashes will be useful because they don't incorporate your random salt.

As in the example posted in the comments, you don't need to do anything special to verify your passwords:

```
pbkdf2_sha256.verify(password, user.hashed_password)
```

There's no need to call `pbkdf2_sha256.encrypt` when verifying a password. `pbkdf2_sha256.verify` does all of this for you.